# Was my answer deleted because it lacked sources, or for another reason?

Tags: discussion, scope, deleted-answers

[Can travellers see Buddhist temples in Saudi Arabia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57870/can-travellers-see-buddhist-temples-in-saudi-arabia)

20 hours ago, I replied to the above question with an answer that explains why Saudi Arabia, even with so many Buddhists, does not have any Buddhist temples. The answer was somewhat controversial judging by the 8 upvotes and 4 downvotes I managed to see through the android app, and was deleted by a moderator, even though it didn't seem against the rules of Travel. I edited my answer to include the sources, because that seemed to be the biggest complaint: that people thought these were opinions, not facts supported by 3rd party sources.

Adding the sources was enough to make the answer undeleted again after pinging the mod. So was this purely because of the sources, or were there other reasons as well?

Comment: possibly since it doesn't answer the question about where to see temples, but normally that'd just get downvotes, rather than deletion, so I'm assuming another reason.

Comment: @markmayo I doubt that is it. I explained part of the reasons why there are no temples, which is an equally good answer in my opinion.

Comment: Seeing as most of the other answers say the same thing.... That said, answer does not appear to be delted to me?

Comment: @CMaster It got undeleted after I added the sources and pinged the mod that deleted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's a barely coherent political rant using inflammatory language, only tangentially related to the question at hand, and that's not what this site is about. As far as the travel-relevant aspect is concerned, you are not adding anything to the other answer. You are not even “explaining” why there are no buddhist temples, you are using this as a pretext to make sweeping political statements (“Even during the Roman Age”!?) and vent opinions.

Even if some of your points might have merit (personally, I am certainly not interested in being dragged in a debate about that), it's political through and through and you know it. So please don't act surprised.

Also, your sources are far from adequate to back up your statements. That there is a severe problem with forced labour and poor working conditions in several places in the region is not in dispute but you are going much further than that and your reasoning does not even make sense on its face. Since the ban on other religions does not exist in other countries in the region with a forced labour problem and also extends to religions that are not associated with migrants from South Asia, your so-called “explanation” seems completely unrelated to the question at hand. You just wanted to rant about slavery and that's a good reason to delete your answer.

Comment: Since I don't care enough about salvaging this, I have simply deleted my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I (partially) own the deletion of your answer. I was working the LQP queue and yours came up because somebody had flagged it.

I saw trenchant language and unsupported assertions.  Either of those alone fit the profile of a low quality post so I voted to delete, and possibly killed it. I am in the users who get a heavier delete vote.  I'm sorry if this was upsetting for you, but you have enough rep to know better.

I upvoted the [comment from jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57870/can-travellers-see-buddhist-temples-in-saudi-arabia#comment118566_57888) (to whom thanks) who I suspect placed your answer in the LQP.

Your answer has been restored, largely intact, so there's a happy ending.  I can see your answer is attracting upvotes and I hope that's satisfying for you also.